# Display Image with data using GridLayout or ListFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

Which one of the following method is best to fetch image and data from local database and display on a fragment.

**Model 1 :**

```
<ListFragment>
      <ListItem>Image+Data(below image)</ListItem>
      <ListItem>Image+Data(below image)</ListItem>
      <ListItem>Image+Data(below image)</ListItem>
      <ListItem>Image+Data(below image)</ListItem>
      <ListItem>Image+Data(below image)</ListItem>
      <ListItem>Image+Data(below image)</ListItem>
      <ListItem>Image+Data(below image)</ListItem>
      <ListItem>Image+Data(below image)</ListItem>
</ListFragment>
```

**Model 2 :**

```
<Fragment>
  <GridLayout>
      <RelativeLayout>Image+Data(below image)</RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout>Image+Data(below image)</RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout>Image+Data(below image)</RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout>Image+Data(below image)</RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout>Image+Data(below image)</RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout>Image+Data(below image)</RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout>Image+Data(below image)</RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout>Image+Data(below image)</RelativeLayout>
  </GridLayout>
<Fragment>
```

**Note :**

I tried to use GridLayout for following reasons,

- Because display multiple columns on tablet landscape mode

But the Gridlayout doesn't have adapter,so I think it may be complex to add child view dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GridView` for this purpose. It has adapter. See an example here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

For dealing with images, i would also take a look at https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader it just makes my life so easy.